# Asp linkbutton always triggering OnClick event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have an asp link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" onclick="Edit_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="confirm()">Edit</asp:LinkButton>

var modalWin = new ModalPopupWindow();
function confirm() {
    var text = document.getElementById('lnkEdit').innerText;
    if (text == "Undo Changes") {
        modalWin.ShowConfirmationMessage("Any unsaved work will be discarded. Do you want to continue?", 200, 200, "Confirmation", "", "Ok", btn1ClickHandler, "Cancel", btn2ClickHandler);
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

If I click the linkbutton, it will show me the `modal.ShowConfirmationMessage`. When I click the `Ok` on the `modal`, that's the time it should consider the `OnClick` event.

The problem here is it is firing both `OnClientClick` and `OnClick`. It will show the modal pop then the page posts back even if i didn't click any button yet.

The handlers:

```
function btn1ClickHandler() {
    // Ok button
        return true;
    }
function btn2ClickHandler() {
        // Cancel button
    }
```

Comment: What is btn1ClickHandler and btn2ClickHandler?

Comment: Try OnClientClick="return confirm()"

Answer (score 0):

You need your Javascript code to return false in the `OnClientClick` event if the modal was Cancel/No. That will prevent the page posting back for the server `OnClick` event.

Or simply:

`OnClientClick="return confirm()"`

Comment: I tried it already. But my linkbutton won't trigger any events anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if` to check whether `OK` button is clicked or not like this

```
if(modalWin.ShowConfirmationMessage("Any unsaved work will be discarded. Do you want to continue?", 200, 200, "Confirmation", "", "Ok", btn1ClickHandler, "Cancel", btn2ClickHandler))
{
  //Your code for Post_back as Ok button is clicked

}
else
{
  //Do Nothing as cancelled button is clicked.
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `return false` on the `if` statement and also by using `return confirm()"`

```
function confirm() {
        var text = document.getElementById('lnkEdit').innerText;
        if (text == "Undo Changes") {
            modalWin.ShowConfirmationMessage("Any unsaved work will be discarded. Do you want to continue?", 200, 200, "Confirmation", "", "Ok", "btn1ClickHandler();", "Cancel", "btn2ClickHandler();");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    };
```